# How to set up a "public" DNS server on linux server?

Tags: dns-server

I need to set up a DNS server to be used with OpenVPN. I can not use conventional public DNS IPs (Like Google public DNS ones) because all of them are blocked in the ISPs where the OpenVPN clients are going to be used,  hence need to define my own.

I appreciate your help.

P.S. I know how to define an authoritative DNS server using nsd3, but nsd3 is authoritative-only and I guess here what I need is a recursive DNS server. I chosen nsd3 after having enormous complexity issues with BIND9, so I hope you can suggest some solution that does not need BIND9.

P.S.2 I just found a nice comparison of DNS servers [here on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software). So I basically know what DNS servers CAN do the job. What I need is HOW to do so.

Answer (score 2):

DNSMasq can do this: http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html

For RHEL based distros, you can do something like this:

```
yum install -y dnsmasq
chkconfig dnsmasq on
service dnsmasq start
```

Then you should be able to point your clients at the IP of the server you just installed it on, and have DNS work nicely.  Make sure the server has valid nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf though.

Comment: Does DNSMasq have a .deb package too? How can I make valid nameservers? Thanks

Comment: It probably does, try searching for it with aptitude (or apt-cache).  You need to include nameserver lines in your /etc/resolv.conf.  This is typically done automatically (if you can access the internet from the machine you are going to run this on, your DNS servers are already set correctly)

Comment: Yup:


    apt-cache search dnsmasq
    dnsmasq-base - A small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
    dnsmasq - A small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
    openresolv - management framework for resolv.conf